# What is the maximum and average power that can be produced by 175 mm crank length

Tags: racing-bikes

Power produced by 175mm crank length in semi recumbent racing bike

Comment: It depends on the human who is doing the cranking and the posture and cadence that they are cycling with.

Comment: In the range from "too short" to "just right", power is proportional to crank length.  Beyond "just right", however, it gets messier.  Mainly, comfort and ergonomic issues become the limiting factors, though at some point the crank is simply too long for the rider to turn (without growing longer legs).

Comment: Cranks don't produce power. People produce power.

Comment: This question can't be answered in any meaningful way as its presented.   I suspect you're trying to find the "best" crank length for your bike, which is notoriously unscientific.  Try borrowing a bunch of cranks and see which "feels" best.   Or if you're lucky enough to own a power meter then get some accurate power numbers for a specific speed.  Remember to try it on the flat as well as up and down a grade for completeness.

Comment: If you're handy with tools, try making some cranks that can be adjusted for length, to narrow down on the length that suits you personally.   I'd love to try longer cranks but 175mm is the longest I've ever found, other than new 180 campag ones at insane cost.

Answer (score 4):

The crank does not generate power. A human does.

As such, crank length is only a part of equation to get power (in Watts): P = F×l×ω, where F is the force one applies (Newtons), l is the distance between axle and pedal (meters) and ω is angular speed (radians per second). The higher the force and rotation frequency, the more the power.

Certain crank lengths may be more comfortable for a given human, thus allowing to achieve higher resulting power. I assume the optimal crank length depends more on legs' geometry, but I doubt that there is a ready equation for that. And do not forget clearance issues — if you take a crank that is too long, it will start interfering with frame or even ground.

The only way a crank could be able to limit power is if it would be possible to break it by applied force. That would require an inhuman strength.

So it is not the crank or even not a bike, it is human. Cranks and bicycles are literally levers in mechanical sense, and the [golden rule of mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_advantage) states that no advantage in power can be achieved with a lever.

Comment: In the early 2000's, [Martin and Spirduso co-authored a series of papers looking at crank length and power production](https://www.google.com/search?q=crank+length+power+martin+spirduso). They found that although there is a statistically significant effect of leg length on "optimal" crank length, the size of the practical effect is small. Perhaps you will consider adding this information to your answer.

Comment: BTW, the reason why Martin and Spirduso look at maximal power rather than average power is because you might think that differences in crank length on power would be more detectable at the limit of output than at average output. That is, if there are differences in power production with crank length, differences in average output would tend to be smaller than differences in maximal output. They observed small differences in max power, so you'd expect differences in average power to be even smaller.

Comment: @R.Chung Unless there is a gross mismatch, can't crank length fit be compensated for with seatpost fit? O does that throw off the front to back fit?

Comment: @JohnP Changing the length of the seatpost affects the distance from the saddle to the BB, but the relationship between the pedal and the saddle also changes at the top, bottom, fore, and aft of the crank cycle. You may be able to adjust the saddle to compensate for crank length at one of those points but not all. Nonetheless, it appears that riders can adapt to a fairly wide range of crank lengths.

Comment: @JohnP While crank length doesn't appear to have much effect on *supply* of power, at least on a TT bike it can have an effect on your positioning and thus on aerodynamic drag, i.e., the demand for power. In TT situations some riders are opting for shorter cranks because it allows them to reduce their overall drag via increased saddle-to-bar drop.

Comment: @R.Chung - That makes sense. I have seen a couple debates about the effect that has for triathletes in being able to run off the bike afterwards, and there is always a debate on compact vs. regular and the same running off the bike implications (Although that is more chainring than crank length)